# Drawing a Cayley tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I'm new to Tikz so sorry if this is trivial. I'd like to draw a Cayley tree in Tikz that looks something like [image: [this] image I found on Google.

The catch is that I want alternating layers to be alternate node shapes -- circle and square nodes. Secondly, I would like the circular nodes to have degree 3 and the square nodes to have degree 5. Is there some way to generate this without having to place each node manually where I want?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In particular, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you have tried so far, and don't give the link to the desired image but upload it using the official Stack Exchange interface, i.e. the image icon on top of the text field (shortcut: Ctrl+G). This ensures that it will always be accessible and won't expire.

Comment: You could use `\usetikzlibrary{trees}` see [Example: Title graphics](http://texample.net/tikz/examples/title-graphics/). If you need further help add a mwe.

Comment: This would be easy with `LuaLaTeX`.  With plain `tikz` it's possible, but too painful for me.

Comment: If 'degree' means what I suspect, I'm with @JPi on this.

Comment: `Degree' means number of adjacent nodes.

Comment: See if this helps : [Cayley Graph of Free Group in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222881/cayley-graph-of-free-group-in-tikz)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Second proposition (using two nested loops as suggested by marsupilam)

*(Note: My previous proposition did not use the correct definition of degrees. Thanks to cfr and marsupilam for having noticed.)*

Here is a `pdflatex` solution. The first node (the center) is `c-0-1`. The first level nodes are `c-1-1`, `c-1-2` and `c-1-3`... The fourth level nodes are `c-4-1`, `c-4-2`, ... and `c-4-96`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  common/.style={draw,name=#1,node contents={},inner sep=0,minimum size=3},
  disc/.style={circle,common=#1},
  square/.style={rectangle,common={#1}},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) node[disc=c-0-1];
  \xdef\radius{0cm}
  \xdef\level{0}
  \xdef\nbnodes{1}
  \xdef\degree{(3+1)} % special degree just for the root node
  \foreach \ndegree/\form in {5/square,3/disc,5/square,3/disc}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro\nlevel{int(\level+1)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\nnbnodes{int(\nbnodes*(\degree-1))}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\nradius{\radius+1cm}
    \draw[red] (c-0-1) circle(\nradius pt);
    \foreach \div in {1,...,\nnbnodes} {
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\src{((\div+\degree-2)/(\degree-1))}
      \path (c-0-1) ++({\div*(360/\nnbnodes)-180/\nnbnodes}:\nradius pt) node[\form=c-\nlevel-\div];
      \draw (c-\level-\src) -- (c-\nlevel-\div);
    }
    \xdef\radius{\nradius}
    \xdef\level{\nlevel}
    \xdef\nbnodes{\nnbnodes}
    \xdef\degree{\ndegree}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So what does the degree stuff mean? I guess my guess was wrong.

Comment: Nice ! More of an art-deco look. Can't we wrap all these in an outer `foreach` loop, by having those `3,12,36,144` computed by an `\xdef` at each turn and with an `\xdef\parity{(1-\parity)}, though ?

Comment: @cfr Paul chose alternating degrees of 3 and 4 instead of 3 and 5. It gets really cramped !

Comment: @marsupilam Isn't this 4 and 5 rather than 3 and 4 or 3 and 5?

Comment: @cfr You are right. I corrected my answer.

Comment: @PaulGaborit Can't vote again, I'm afraid, but I appreciate the comment as I was trying to figure out the 'degree' stuff and first your answer and then marsupilam's comment above really confused me.

Answer (score 12):

I followed the advice by JPi and cfr, and went for lua.

*(edit : I think this style gives a nice blooming sakura vibe.)*

### The output

[image]

### The `tikz`

Compile with `lualatex`

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
  print=tex.print
  makeGrow=require("makeGrow.lua")
\end{luacode*}
\begin{document}
\tikzset
{
  odd/.style = {draw=blue!50!pink,circle,ultra thick},
  even/.style = {draw=red,line width=3pt,minimum size=4mm},
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=20]
  \directlua{makeGrow.make(4)}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### The `lua`

```
-- makeGrow.lua
-- mode = {totalAngle = totalAngle, number = numberOfChildren, radius = lengthOrArm}
local function makeChildren(parent,mode,f)
  local f = f or function() return end
  parent.children = {}
  for k=1,mode.number do
    parent.children[k] = {
      generation = parent.generation + 1,
      angle = parent.angle + (k-.5*(mode.number+1)) * mode.totalAngle / mode.number,
      parent = parent,
      label = parent.label .. tostring(k),
    }
    f(parent.children[k]) -- we smuggled f in there to recurse.
  end
end
local function tikzNode(node)
  return {
    name = "(myNode-" .. node.label .. ")",
    style = "[" .. ({"even","odd"})[node.generation%2+1] .. "]",
  }
end
local function draw(node,mode)
  if node.parent then
    print([[\path]] .. tikzNode(node.parent).name .. " -- ++(" .. node.angle .. ":" ..  mode.radius .. ") node" .. tikzNode(node).style .. tikzNode(node).name .. "{} ;")
    print([[\draw]] .. tikzNode(node.parent).name .. " -- " .. tikzNode(node).name .. ";")
  else
    print([=[\node[odd]]=] .. tikzNode(node).name .. "at (0,0) {};")
  end
end
local function drawMakeChild(n,modes)
  local function recurse(node)
      draw(node,modes[node.generation-1])
      if node.generation<=n then
        makeChildren(node,modes[node.generation],recurse)
      end
  end
  return recurse
end
local function computeMode(generation,hash)
  local number = ({5,3})[generation%2+1] -- alternating number of children
  local radius = hash.radRatio^generation
  local totalAngle = 360 * hash.angRatio^(generation-1)
  return {totalAngle = totalAngle , number = number, radius = radius}
end
local function make(n)
  local origin = {
    generation = 1,
    angle = 0,
    label = ""
  }
  local modes = {}
  for k=1,n do modes[k] = computeMode(k,{angRatio=.98,radRatio=.35}) end
  drawMakeChild(n,modes)(origin)
end
return {make=make}
```

### Edit : Using Paul's style

#### The output

[image]

or with `\def\N{4}`

[image]

#### The `tikz`

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
  print=tex.print
  makeGrow=require("paulStyle.lua")
\end{luacode*}
\begin{document}
\tikzset
{
  commons/.style={fill=white},
  odd/.style = {draw=red,circle,ultra thick,commons},
  even/.style = {draw=blue,ultra thick,minimum size=3mm,commons},
}
\def\N{3}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
  \foreach \k in {1,...,\N} \draw[help lines,purple] (0,0) circle (\k);
  \directlua{makeGrow.make(\N)}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### The `lua`

```
-- paulStyle.lua
local function makeChildren(parent,multiplicity,f)
  parent.children = {}
  for k=1,multiplicity do
    parent.children[k] = {
      generation = parent.generation + 1,
      cumProd = parent.cumProd * multiplicity,
      angle = parent.angle + ((k-.5)/multiplicity-.5 ) * 360 / parent.cumProd,
      parent = parent,
      label = parent.label .. tostring(k),
    }
    f(parent.children[k]) -- we smuggled f in there to recurse.
  end
end
local function tikzNode(node)
  return {
    name = "(myNode-" .. node.label .. ")",
    style = "[" .. ({"odd","even"})[node.generation%2+1] .. "]",
  }
end
local function draw(node)
  if node.parent then
    print([[\node]].. tikzNode(node).style .. tikzNode(node).name .. " at " .. "(" .. node.angle .. ":" ..  node.generation .. ") {};")
    print([[\draw]] .. tikzNode(node.parent).name .. " -- " .. tikzNode(node).name .. ";")
  else
    print([=[\node]=] .. tikzNode(node).style .. tikzNode(node).name .. "at (0,0) {};")
  end
end
local function drawMakeChild(n,multiplicities)
  local function recurse(node)
      draw(node,multiplicities[node.generation-1])
      if node.generation<n then
        makeChildren(node,multiplicities[node.generation],recurse)
      end
  end
  return recurse
end
local function make(n)
  local origin = {
    cumProd = 1,
    generation = 0,
    angle = 0,
    label = ""
  }
  local multiplicities = {}
  for k=1,n do multiplicities[k-1] = ({5,3})[k%2+1] end
  drawMakeChild(n,multiplicities)(origin)
end
return {make=make}
```

Comment: Nice. This isn't actually what I had in mind. (Was more thinking of the `graphs` stuff.) But very neat!

Comment: Thanks @cfr I find lua absolutely fun ! I just learnt about closures during this summer vacation (had only read about them in the vim documentation...!) I'm so grateful to luaLaTeX for offering me this new universe.

Comment: I am very impressed as I know nothing at all about Lua.

Comment: That's pretty!!

Comment: Thanks so much! This looks fabulous! I had to choose a right answer to resolve this but all the answers are really good.

Answer (score 10):

Here's mine. Despite my comments, this is, in fact, pure Ti*k*Z without any of the `graphs` stuff. That is, you can compile it with LaTeX, pdfLaTeX or whatever and it should work. (You can presumably convert it into a TeX version, should you so wish.) I planned to use `graphs` to draw the connections, which doesn't need LuaTeX anyway. But, somehow, I never got around to it as, once I'd placed the nodes, this seemed easier.

Change the maximum value for the outer loop to increase the number of levels. I practised with values of 3 and 4, but use 5 for the 'display' version here. The complication is that the first node gets 3 children, in order to have degree 3, while later nodes of degree 3 only need 2, because they have a parent. This requires special treatment of the first 3 levels to get things to line up correctly. After that, subsequent levels are just a question of TeX capacity and your patience.

Use `\showtrue` to draw a labelled version, for debugging purposes.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newif\ifshow\showfalse % set true to debug
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % \i: level \s: shape \a: angle \t: turn \d: degree -1 \j: number \m: rotation \g: group \k: number \c: colour
  \def\j{1}\def\dlast{1}\def\tlast{0}
  \foreach \i [remember=\i as \ilast] in {0,...,5}
  {
    \draw [darkgray] (0,0) circle (\i cm);
    \pgfmathsetmacro\a{360/\j}
    \ifodd\i\def\s{}\def\c{magenta}\def\d{4}\pgfmathsetmacro\t{\tlast-1.5*\a}\else\def\c{blue!50!cyan}\def\s{circle}\def\d{2}\pgfmathsetmacro\t{\tlast-2.5*\a}\fi
    \ifnum\i=1\pgfmathsetmacro\t{-\a}\fi
    \ifnum\i=0\def\d{3}\def\t{0}\fi
    \foreach \k [evaluate=\k as \m using {(\k*\a)+\t}, evaluate=\k as \g using {int((floor((\k-1)/\dlast)))}, count=\n from 0 ] in {1,...,\j}
    {
      \ifshow\def\tempa{n-\i-\g-\n:\k}\else\let\tempa\relax\fi
      \node (n-\i-\n) [draw, fill, \c, \s, minimum size=2.5pt, inner sep=0pt, label={[font=\tiny]{\tempa}} ] at (\m:\i cm) {};
      \ifnum\i>0 \draw [darkgray] (n-\i-\n) -- (n-\ilast-\g); \fi
    }
    \pgfmathsetmacro\j { \j*\d }
    \global\let\j\j
    \global\let\dlast\d
    \pgfmathsetmacro\tlast{(\i==1) ? 0 : (\t+\a) }
    \global\let\tlast\tlast
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Cayley tree]

Here's a more parametized version, with (optional) special effects.

- `circle colour=<colour>` will give a uniform colour for the circles;
- `circle colours=<colour>:<colour>` will give shades varying between the two colours for the circles;
- `square colour=<colour>` will give a uniform colour for the circles;
- `square colours=<colour>:<colour>` will give shades varying between the two colours for the squares;
- `circle degree=<integer>` sets the degree for the circular nodes;
- `square degree=<integer>` sets the degree for the square nodes;
- `connection colour<colour>` sets the colour for the circles and the background;
- `levels=<integer>` sets the number of levels.

If you don't want the background, just delete the line

```
\scoped[on background layer]{\shade [inner color=lcol!5, outer color=lcol!35] circle (\l cm);}
```

In that case, you don't need the `backgrounds` library and can delete

```
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
```

if you don't need it for anything else.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\newif\ifshow\showfalse % set true to debug
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % \i: level \s: shape \a: angle \t: turn \d: degree -1 \j: number \m: rotation \g: group \k: number ncol: colour
  \tikzset{
    circle degree/.code={\def\dr{#1}\pgfmathsetmacro\dc{int(#1-1)}\pgfmathsetmacro\tc{((\dc-1)/2)+1}},
    square degree/.code={\pgfmathsetmacro\ds{int(#1-1)}\pgfmathsetmacro\ts{((\ds-1)/2)+1}},
    levels/.code={\pgfmathsetmacro\l{int(#1-1)}},
    connection colour/.code={\colorlet{lcol}{#1}},
    circle colours/.code args={#1:#2}{\colorlet{ccol1}{#1}\colorlet{ccol2}{#2}},
    square colours/.code args={#1:#2}{\colorlet{scol1}{#1}\colorlet{scol2}{#2}},
    circle colour/.style={circle colours=#1:#1},
    square colour/.style={square colours=#1:#1},
    circle degree=3,
    square degree=5,
    levels=6,
    connection colour=darkgray,
    square colours=green:blue,
    circle colours=blue:magenta,
  }
  \def\j{1}\def\dlast{1}\def\tlast{0}
  \foreach \i [remember=\i as \ilast] in {0,...,\l}
  {
    \draw [lcol] (0,0) circle (\i cm);
    \pgfmathsetmacro\a{360/\j}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\z{6.5-\i*.8}
    \ifodd\i\def\s{}\colorlet{ncol1}{scol1}\colorlet{ncol2}{scol2}\let\d\dc\pgfmathsetmacro\t{\tlast-\ts*\a}\else\colorlet{ncol1}{ccol1}\colorlet{ncol2}{ccol2}\def\s{circle}\let\d\ds\pgfmathsetmacro\t{\tlast-\tc*\a}\fi
    \ifnum\i=1\pgfmathsetmacro\t{-\a}\fi
    \ifnum\i=0\let\d\dr\def\t{0}\fi
    \foreach \k [evaluate=\k as \m using {(\k*\a)+\t}, evaluate=\k as \g using {int((floor((\k-1)/\dlast)))}, count=\n from 0, evaluate=\k as \p using { (\k > \j/2) ? ((1-\k/\j)*200) : ((200/\j)*\k)} ] in {1,...,\j}
    {
      \ifshow\def\tempa{n-\i-\g-\n:\k}\else\let\tempa\relax\fi
      \node (n-\i-\n) [draw, fill, ncol1!\p!ncol2, \s, minimum size=\z pt, inner sep=0pt, label={[font=\tiny]{\tempa}} ] at (\m:\i cm) {};
      \ifnum\i>0 \draw [ncol1!\p!ncol2] (n-\i-\n) -- (n-\ilast-\g); \fi
    }
    \pgfmathsetmacro\j { \j*\d }
    \global\let\j\j
    \global\let\dlast\d
    \pgfmathsetmacro\tlast{(\i==1) ? 0 : (\t+\a) }
    \global\let\tlast\tlast
  }
  \scoped[on background layer]{\shade [inner color=lcol!5, outer color=lcol!35] circle (\l cm);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: fancier version]