# Positioning a node with node label

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

This question is related to a question I'd asked earlier on this thread:

[Drawing a Cayley tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385018/drawing-a-cayley-tree)

I have some for loops creating a graph and I'd like to position a node OVER another node whose co-ordinates I don't know.

For instance, let's say the for loop generates a node at (1.35, 0.8). I'd like to place another node at those co-ordinates, masking the original node there. These are rather odd co-ordinates that I can only find by trial and error and is rather tedious. Is there a way to position a node using something along the lines of

```
\node[disc] at (c-1-1) {};
```

where disc is some pre-specified shape and (c-1-1) is the node at (1.35,0.8) that I'd like to mask?

Apologies if this has already been asked. I searched for how to position a node using another node's label on Google and every response was how to position a node label.

Thanks

Comment: I assume you're using the accepted answer from that other question. If you try `\node[circle,fill=blue] at (c-1-1) {};` you'll see that it works perfectly fine. For some reason though the `disc` style defined in that answer doesn't work after the loop, I don't know why. Note though that that style takes an argument, i.e.  it should be used as `disc=namefornode`.

Comment: `\path (c-1-1) node[disc=b];` works.

Comment: Thank you, that works! Yes I did use the accepted answer from that question.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. My `disc` style requires an argument *and* defines a node without content: it uses an empty `node contents` option.

Comment: @PaulGaborit Yes, I realized that eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just posting this separately here so that I can mark this thread answered.

Torbjørn T.'s answer works.

```
\path (c-1-1) node[disc=b];
```

Thank you!