# Cayley graph of with generators emphasized by color

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, tikz-styles

I am trying to make the Cayley graph of a free group of rank 2 in TikZ. The result I would like to obtain looks like this:

[image]

but arrows are not required. I read [Cayley Graph of Free Group in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222881/cayley-graph-of-free-group-in-tikz) and tried to figure out Lindemayer systemts, as this is what most answers go by. However, this goes way over my head and I also could not figure out how to use the different coloring (which is the most important feature I am after).

As I don't know how to adjust the Lindemayer system answers to get the different coloring, there is little advantage of giving a minimal working example, as I simply copied one of the answers in the linked question and tried to figure out the code and how to add the color. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT** I also tried to do some work manually and than rotate the whole: I defined the nodes on the right manually, than tried using the rotation macro, but this did not work, I can include this:

```
  \begin{standalone}
  \usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (2,0);
\coordinate (C) at (3,0);
\coordinate (D) at (3.5, 0);
\coordinate (E) at (2,1);
\coordinate (F) at (2,1.5);
\coordinate (G) at (2,-1);
\coordinate (H) at (2,-1.5);
\coordinate (I) at (1.5, -1);
\coordinate (J) at (2.5, -1);
\coordinate (K) at (1.5, 1);
\coordinate (L) at (2.5, 1);
\coordinate (M) at (3, 0.5);
\coordinate (N) at (3,-0.5);
\foreach \angle \in {0,90,180,-90}
\begin{scope}[rotate=\angle]
\foreach \point in {A,B,..., N}
\fill [black] (\point) circle (2pt);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but this did not work, I only received the nodes I initially defined... (I am very new to TikZ as you can see, I tried looking up the scope environment in the PGF manuel to see what I did wrong, but I think I don't really understand this environment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lindenmayersystems` library seems the way to go here. A variation from [Cayley Graph of Free Group in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223078/13304). The caveat is to change color of the style depending on the quadrant:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems,arrows.meta}
\newcount\quadrant
\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{cayley}{
  \rule{A -> B [ R [A] [+A] [-A] ]}
  \symbol{R}{ \pgflsystemstep=0.5\pgflsystemstep } 
  \symbol{-}{
    \pgfmathsetcount\quadrant{Mod(\quadrant+1,4)}
    \tikzset{rotate=90}
  }
  \symbol{+}{
    \pgfmathsetcount\quadrant{Mod(\quadrant-1,4)}
    \tikzset{rotate=-90}
  }
  \symbol{B}{
    \ifnumodd{\quadrant}{%true
        \tikzset{dot-cayley/.append style={draw=red}}
    }{%false
        \tikzset{dot-cayley/.append style={draw=blue}}
    }   
    \draw [dot-cayley] (0,0) -- (\pgflsystemstep,0) 
       node [font=\footnotesize, midway, 
         anchor={270-mod(\the\quadrant,2)*90}, inner sep=.5ex] 
           {};
    \tikzset{xshift=\pgflsystemstep}
  }
}
\tikzset{
  dot/.tip={Circle[sep=-1.5pt,length=3pt]}, cayley/.tip={dot[]}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw l-system [l-system={cayley, axiom=[A] [+A] [-A] [++A], step=5cm, order=4}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

With black dots at the end of the segment:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems,arrows.meta}
\newcount\quadrant
\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{cayley}{
  \rule{A -> B [ R [A] [+A] [-A] ]}
  \symbol{R}{ \pgflsystemstep=0.5\pgflsystemstep } 
  \symbol{-}{
    \pgfmathsetcount\quadrant{Mod(\quadrant+1,4)}
    \tikzset{rotate=90}
  }
  \symbol{+}{
    \pgfmathsetcount\quadrant{Mod(\quadrant-1,4)}
    \tikzset{rotate=-90}
  }
  \symbol{B}{
    \ifnumodd{\quadrant}{%true
        \tikzset{dot-cayley-color/.style={draw=red}}
    }{%false
        \tikzset{dot-cayley-color/.style={draw=blue}}
    }   
    \draw [dot-cayley,dot-cayley-color] (0,0) -- (\pgflsystemstep,0) 
       node [font=\footnotesize, midway, 
         anchor={270-mod(\the\quadrant,2)*90}, inner sep=.5ex] 
           {};
    \tikzset{xshift=\pgflsystemstep}
  }
}
\tikzset{
  dot/.tip={Circle[sep=-1.5pt,length=3pt,color=black]}, cayley/.tip={dot[color=black]}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw l-system [l-system={cayley, axiom=[A] [+A] [-A] [++A], step=5cm, order=4}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Would it be easy to add the black nodes using this code? Or could I somehow use the small part of code I had to add those?

Comment: Yes, it is quite easy. I'll add a revision of the code for this

Comment: I have increased your score +1. Very good.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a brute force example. The idea is that it is so simple that you can easily adjust it to your needs.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1pt,scale=0.5]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Radius}{4}
\foreach \X in {0,...,3}
{\coordinate (X\X) at ({\X*90}:\Radius);
\ifodd\X
\draw[blue](0,0) -- (X\X);
\else
\draw[red](0,0) -- (X\X);
\fi
\foreach \Y in {1,2,3}
{
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\sumOne}{\X+\Y}
\ifodd\sumOne
\draw[blue] (X\X) -- ++({(\X+\Y-2)*90}:{\Radius/2.5}) coordinate (X\X-\Y);
\else
\draw[red] (X\X) -- ++({(\X+\Y-2)*90}:{\Radius/2.5}) coordinate (X\X-\Y);
\fi
\foreach \Z in {1,2,3}
{
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\sumTwo}{\X+\Y+\Z}
\ifodd\sumTwo
\draw[blue] (X\X-\Y) -- ++({(\X+\Y+\Z-4)*90}:{\Radius/2.5^2}) coordinate (X\X-\Y-\Z);
\else
\draw[red] (X\X-\Y) -- ++({(\X+\Y+\Z-4)*90}:{\Radius/2.5^2}) coordinate (X\X-\Y-\Z);
\fi
\foreach \V in {1,2,3}
{
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\sumThree}{\X+\Y+\Z+\V}
\ifodd\sumThree
\draw[blue] (X\X-\Y-\Z) -- ++({(\X+\Y+\Z+\V-2)*90}:{\Radius/2.5^3}) coordinate
(X\X-\Y-\Z-\V);
\else
\draw[red] (X\X-\Y-\Z) -- ++({(\X+\Y+\Z+\V-2)*90}:{\Radius/2.5^3}) coordinate
(X\X-\Y-\Z-\V);
\fi
}
}
}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'll have to take a closer look at it, trying to figure out what exactly is going on. One last question: would it be easy to add the black dots at branch points? Could I use any of the 'code' I wrote for this?